# Python - TypeError: (function) takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) - but I only gave 2!

Tags: python

I'm parsing a list of patient visits (csv file). To deal with this, I have a custom set of classes:

```
class Patient:
    def __init__(self,Rx,ID):
    ....

class PtController:
    def __init__(self,openCSVFile):
        self.dict=DictReader(openCSVFile)
        self.currentPt = ''
        ....

    def initNewPt(self,row):
        Rx = row['Prescription']
        PatientID = row['PatientID']
        self.currentPt = Patient(Rx,PatientID)
        ...
```

So, I'm using the csv.DictReader to process the file; built into the PtController class. It iterates through, but to set values for the first patient does the following:

```
firstRow = self.dict.next()
self.initNewPt(self,firstRow)
    ...
```

The error:

```
TypeError: initNewPt() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

If I print(firstRow) before calling initNewPt, it prints the row in dictionary form as expected.

Using python2.7, and this is my first time working with objects. Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need to pass `self` directly as in `self.initNewPt(self,firstRow)`, since it is automatically passed implicitly by Python.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I'm assuming when I pass (self, otherVariable), python is intercepting and passing --> (self,self, otherVariable) - hence 3 total arguments?

Answer (score 5):

When you call `self.initNewPt()` you should not pass `self` as a parameter.  This is an implied parameter that's automatically present.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the `initNewPt` without the `self` argument within a class method:

```
self.initNewPt(firstRow)
```